# Custom sharepoint (poweapp) form lookup

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have a Sharepoint list that an end user has to populate through the form as per the screenshot below.

This custom form has a dropdown menu based on a lookup from another list. The problem is that the drop down should only show the title with the associated name of the person appearing below when a dropdown selection has been made.

[image]

The form should now show the name associated with the current PDM based on what I selected.

[image]

It does do so when I add the respective datacard. However the name displayed does not change based on the selection in the dropdown but is stuck with the selection I made when adding the card in powerapps. 
Please see below the code behind the "Name" datacard...

[image]

I must add that I am a novice at power apps so please bear with me if I am not totally up to speed like some of you might be.

Many thanks and best regards,

Tom.

Comment: Can you help with letting know what do you want to achieve

Comment: I’ve added some more details. The main thing I am trying is to have a name appear based on a drop down selection. Ideally that name would be referenced to a list so that i wouldn’t have to change the form via powerapp whenever there is a change in personnel.

Comment: Do you mean that you want user name to be displayed based on dropdown selection from another list?

Comment: that's exactly what I am trying to do. The aim is to have the Person behind the job title displayed in the form when making a selection from the dropdown. The dropdown menu contains job titles from persons in sharepoint.

Comment: Did it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get the value and set to a control like label from people picker control in power apps.

1. Select your label:- in property select "Text" and text write below
   formula

   ```
   DataCardValue.Selected.DisplayName
   ```
2. Create a local variable and assign the value to the label

People picker on change property

```
UpdateContext({oPDMName:DataCardValue.Selected.DisplayName})
```

And on label text property

```
oPDMNAme
```